# Force a notification to be swipeable

Tags: notifications

I have a notification from Google Play Services about a ROM update that is stickied in my notification tray:

[image]

I want to make it possible to swipe away the lower notification. I am rooted with XPosed installed, however I can't find any solution online.

I'm running Lolipop 5.1 on my Verizon HTC M8.